# IProgress<T>.Report works in second for loop, but not the first one

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working on a game that requires a lengthy world generation method, and as such I am working on adding a loading screen.
Inside my generation method, there are 4 for loops(2 and 4 are nested inside 1 and 3).
I am using Task.Run to run my generation on a thread, and using IProgress.Report() to report my progress.
This works perfectly in the second set of loops, but not in the first one.
This is my first forray into threading so I am not sure where to begin with debugging the issue, Hence I am asking here.
Relevant code included below.

First class:

```
var progressHandler = new Progress<int>(value =>
{
    prog.Value = value; //prog is a progress bar
});
var progress = (IProgress<int>) progressHandler;

_result = Task.Run(() =>
{
    var world = WorldTools.GenerateWorld(0, 500, 500, tileSet, "World", 24, tilesPath, progress);
    return world;
 });
```

Second Class(WorldTools.GenerateWorld()):

```
try
{
    //Do some stuff
    for (var i = point; i < (gridX + point); i++)
    {
        for (var j = point; j < (gridY + point); j++)
        {
            //Copy value from [i,j] to another array
            z++;
            progress.Report(z);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Catch the exception.
}

for (var i = 0; i < world.Grid.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < world.Grid.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        //Several conditionals, create an object based on value
        z++;
        progress.Report(z);
    }
}
```

The redacted code is very basic stuff, Just some conditionals or array operations. The first for loop is executed almost immediately, while the second one is executed about 15s later. I only redact for verbosity, If the full source if needed I will present it.
Again, The problem is that progress.Report(z) doesnt appear to be firing in the first set of loops, but it works as expected in the second. I know that the first set of loops run as I expect because the Z value does iterate and is at the expected value when we arrive at the second set of loops.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is probably running when the class constructor is created for the grid before any data is collected.  Normally I add a check to the grid event to make sure there are rows (row count > 0) in the grid before doing any processing.

Comment: @jdweng, there is data in the grid. I should add that when I reach the second set of loops, the z value is at the expected value so the loops are running as I expect, just the reporting isnt.

Comment: After update a grid make sure you set the datasource to null and then back to actual data.  Some grids the paint method isn't automatically called so the data isn't refreshed.  Setting the datasource to null and back to actual data will call the paint method and refresh the grid.

Comment: How are you verifying that progress is not reported? Are you observing the response of the UI or are you breaking into code / checking logs?

Comment: @Gusdor, watching the UI. The progress bar doesn't update during the first loop, but then jumps to 50% and progresses as expected with the second.

Comment: @HamishW Is the UI responsive during the load operation? If it is not, you are changing the progress too often. `Progress<T>`automatically marshals back to the UI thread. Try updating progress every half second instead. I also recommend using a logging framework (nlog, log4net, etc) or at least `Debug.WriteLine()`so you can see what the application is doing under the covers.

Comment: @Gusdor, The UI does remain responsive. Good suggestion with the logger, I added the progress value to the logs and it does appear as though it is firing the event as expected, so the issue is with the progress bar and not the handling of the progress as I thought. Thanks! As i'm new around these parts, is it kosher to delete the OP as its no longer relevant?

Comment: It would be really super if you can post your solution as an answer, even  if your initial assumption of the cause  was wrong.

Comment: @HamishW answer your question, don't delete it